# Boto3 is giving botocore.exceptions.ConnectTimeoutError: Connect timeout on endpoint URL: on Linux server

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, amazon-s3, boto3

Below code is working on Windows but on Linux server giving error. I am able to hit endpoint from linux server by using Firewall, ping and telnet.

````
import boto3
from botocore.client import Config
import boto3

config = Config(connect_timeout=5, retries={'max_attempts': 0})
aws_access_key_id = "aws_access_key_id"
aws_secret_access_key = "aws_secret_access_key"
host = "http://s3path",)

session = boto3.Session()

s1 = session.resource('s3', config=config)
s3 = boto3.client('s3',endpoint_url=host, aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key,config=config)

# Print out bucket names
contents = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket='bucket',  MaxKeys=1000, Prefix='prefix')['Contents']
print(contents)```

Error:
raise ConnectTimeoutError(endpoint_url=request.url, error=e)
botocore.exceptions.ConnectTimeoutError: Connect timeout on endpoint URL:
````

Comment: Just to be clear - Are you able to ping `s3.aws.com-datahub`? Or is that an example URL?

Comment: Please ignore these valuesaws_access_key_id = "aws_access_key_id", aws_secret_access_key = "aws_secret_access_key", host = "hostname". Because i have mentioned dummy values.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test using your code since you didn't include the parts that are failing, but I can tell you that you don't typically need the endpoint_url.  Here's the relevant part from the docs

> endpoint_url (string) -- The complete URL to use for the constructed
> client. Normally, **botocore will automatically construct the
> appropriate URL to use when communicating with a service**.

Here's my version of your code that works.  Ran from inside AWS Cloud Shell.

```
import boto3
from botocore.client import Config

bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"
config = Config(connect_timeout=5, retries={'max_attempts': 0})
session = boto3.Session()

s3_client = session.client('s3', config=config)

# Print out bucket names
contents = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket_name)['Contents']
print(contents)
```